# PerlTk Label - Different colour text in same widget

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I have written a GUI which interacts with our psql database. For a given date, the gui displays a person list with various identifiers and bits of information. I use Tk::Table to display the data

```
eg
my $f_mainframe = $mw -> Frame(-bg=>'white');
$f_mainframe -> pack(-side=>'top', -expand=>1, -fill=>'both');
my $itable = $f_mainframe -> Table(-rows => 13,
                   -columns=>30,
                   -fixedrows => 1,
                   -fixedcolumns => 1,
                   -relief => 'raised') -> pack();

$itable->put(1,$firstnamecol,"First Name\nMYO");
```

Is it possible to colour "First Name" in black and "MYO" in Red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `->put` method on a `Tk::Table` with a string argument, a simple `Tk::Label` widget is created. Labels can only be configured to have a single foreground color. To achieve what you want you can use a `Tk::ROText` (a read-only text widget) instead. The following code displays a label widget and a text widget, but the latter with different colors:

```
use strict;
use Tk;
use Tk::ROText;

my $mw = tkinit;

# The monocolored Label variant
my $l = $mw->Label
    (
     -text => "First Name\nMYO",
     -font => "{sans serif} 12",
    )->pack;

# The multicolored ROText variant
my $txt = $mw->ROText
    (
     -borderwidth => 0, -highlightthickness => 0, # remove extra borders
     -takefocus => 0, # make widget unfocusable
     -font => "{sans serif} 12",
    )->pack;
$txt->tagConfigure
    (
     'blue',
     -foreground => "blue",
     -justify => 'center', # to get same behavior as with Tk::Label
    );
$txt->tagConfigure
    (
     'red',
     -foreground => "red",
     -justify => 'center', # to get same behavior as with Tk::Label
    );
$txt->insert("end", "First Name\n", "blue", "MYO", "red");
# a hack to make the ROText geometry the same as the Label geometry
$txt->GeometryRequest($l->reqwidth, $l->reqheight);

MainLoop;
```

As you see, it's much more typing to get the text widget variant working. So it's probably useful to abstract this code into a subroutine or a widget class (maybe something for CPAN?). Note also that you have to deal with text widget's geometry yourself. The label extends automatically to accommodate the label contents. A text widget has by default a geometry of 80x24 characters, and does not shrink or extend automatically based on its contents. In the sample I used a hack using `GeometryRequest` to force the same geometry as the equivalent label widget. Maybe you're fine with hardcoding `-width` and `-height` instead. Another solution could be to use the `bbox()` method of `Tk::Text`/`Tk::ROText` to calculate the geometry.